# Activeadmin: Could not find arbre-1.0.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, arbre

I'm trying to run `rails g active_admin:install` script after installing of `activeadmin` gem. When I run this script I get an error

```
Could not find arbre-1.0.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Although I've already installed all necessary gems and my app is using `arbre` gem:

```
Using arbre 1.0.1
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'spring', group: :development

gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

How can I fix that problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the wrong gemset for the app. For me solution was `rvm use 2.1.1@your_gemset` and restarting terminal

Comment: Great news. You can accept your own answer if you want.

Comment: @SergioLopezMendez anyway, thanks for help and participation :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/3216. Although the cause of the problem is not mentioned they recommend deleting `Gemfile.lock` and running `bundle install` again.

Comment: Can you share your `Gemfile`?

Comment: I just created a new project with the same gemfile and everything went smoothly when running the ActiveAdmin generator. What happens when you install the gem directly via `gem install arbre --version=1.0.1` ?

Comment: it's strange, but every time I install it directly it is installing again, but the error remains

Comment: when I run `bundle show arbre` it shows `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@app/gems/arbre-1.0.1`